# Reg: inner join queries

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table employee_table (employee_id number,employee_name varchar2(100),employee_designation varchar2(100),joining_date date,record_updated_date date);
insert all
into employee_table values(24321,'john','consultant','01-Jan-18','01-Jan-18')
into employee_table values(24322,'andrew','senior business analyst','01-Jan-15','01-Jan-15')
into employee_table values(24322,'andrew','consultant','01-Jan-18','01-Jan-17')
into employee_table values(24322,'andrew','senior consultant','01-Jan-15','01-Jan-19')
into employee_table values(24323,'simons','senior business analyst','01-Jan-17','01-Jan-17')
into employee_table values(24323,'simons','consultant','01-Jan-17','01-Jan-19')
select * from dual;

create table salary_table(employee_id number,year number,salary number);
insert all
into salary_table values(24321,2018,30000)
into salary_table values(24321,2019,30000)
into salary_table values(24322,2015,25000)
into salary_table values(24322,2016,25000)
into salary_table values(24322,2017,30000)
into salary_table values(24322,2018,30000)
into salary_table values(24322,2019,35000)
into salary_table values(24323,2017,25000)
into salary_table values(24323,2018,25000)
into salary_table values(24323,2019,30000)
select * from dual;
```

i have created two tables now i want to write query to get the total salary drawn by each employee till date.
kindly help me with solution

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for test case.

It seems that you know *everything* you have to do; I'm not sure why you didn't do it already.

```
SQL> select e.employee_name,
  2         sum(s.salary) total_salary
  3  from (select distinct e1.employee_id,
  4                        e1.employee_name
  5        from employee_table e1
  6       ) e join salary_table s on s.employee_id = e.employee_id
  7  where s.year <= 2017
  8  group by e.employee_name;

EMPLOYEE_NAME        TOTAL_SALARY
-------------------- ------------
simons                      25000
andrew                      80000

SQL>
```

This is what you said - and that's what code does:

- I want to write query - it is right here
- to get the total salary - see line 2, the `sum` function
- drawn by each employee - it is in line #1; I selected their names, you could select something else. Just pay attention to the `GROUP BY` clause (line #8): columns that aren't aggregated have to be included into it.

  - another objection: your `employee_table` contains several rows per employee (based on where they worked during the years); that's why I used an inline view (lines #3 - 5) to fetch distinct employees' data
- till date - that's probably a parameter, but nonetheless, it is in line #7

Comment: Dont you think, empid 24323 should have total salary as 55000 but your query will show it as only 50000.

Comment: That's an excellent observation, @Ankit! Thank you. The fact is, Simmons earned only 25.000 for years <= 2017. My result was doubled because I didn't realize that employees table contains several records per employee, so salary was multiplied by number of rows in that table. Fixed now.

Comment: Even this doesn't answer OP. Coz Simmons have earned 55000 till 2019.

Comment: @Ankit, my query returns salaries till <= 2017. If the OP wants some different year, no problem in changing that year to 2019 (as you said) or - even better - use a parameter.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks for answer.